# Why am I able to ping hostnames defined in ~/.ssh/config?

Tags: ssh, ping

This isn't a problem I'm trying to solve, but it's something I've been curious about for a while.

I have defined several hostnames in ~/.ssh/config, but not anywhere else. Notably, I have not defined anything in /etc/hosts.

But I've noticed that I am able to ping these hotnames. Why is this? Does the ping utility specifically look in ~/.ssh/config? Or is it an OS-wide thing? Does it have something to do with DNS?

Edit:

To be more specific, I have defined a host in ~/.ssh/config thus:

```
Host my_laptop
        Hostname 192.168.1.3
        Port 22
        User myname
```

...and I could `ping my_laptop` from another machine, on the same local network, and it resolves to `192.168.1.3`. This confused me because "my_laptop" isn't defined anywhere else, so I assumed `ping` was getting this hostname from the ssh config.

**HOWEVER**, user Kusalananda mentioned `nslookup` and `dig` (two commands which I was unfamiliar with until now), and running `nslookup my_laptop` from another machine returns:

```
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Name:   my_laptop.home
Address: 192.168.1.3
```

`192.168.1.1` is the address of my home router, and I know that port 53 has something to do with DNS. I poked around in my router's settings and the machine in question ('my_laptop`) is also known by that same hostname in the router's list of machines in the local network.

So, I guess what is happening is that my home router is also a DNS server, and none of this has anything to do with the entries in ~/.ssh/config, and as you *may* be able to tell, I am not well versed in networking in general and DNS in particular. And in fact this question probably doesn't belong here but in another section of Stack Exchange; sorry about that.

Comment: Depending on what you mean, yes, this is very strange, or no, this is entirely ordinary. A hostname has to be resolvable to be able to ping it, or to be able to connect to it via `ssh`, so that's not strange. The `ssh` configuration file can also define "labels" for hosts that may _not_ be resolvable, other than by looking up the corresponding hostname in the configuration and resolving that, which is what `ssh` is doing, but which `ping` would probably not be able to do by itself.  In short, share a not-private part of your `~/.ssh/config` file so that we can see what you actually mean.

Comment: `Host my_laptop
        Hostname 192.168.1.3
        Port 22
        User myname` I can then "ping my_laptop" and it indeed resolves to `192.168.1.3`

Comment: Ok, and what is the name that you can ping, from what machine? What does `nslookup` or `dig` return for the same name?  It would be better if you could add clarifications to the question instead of in the comments.

Comment: Okay, I've added more information, and now I think this has nothing to do with the ssh config, but thanks to your mention of the `nslookup` command, I think I understand what is happening: that the hostname i'm pinging just happens to match the hostname supplied from my router's DNS server, and I was confusing correlation with causation. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: No need to be apologetic (regarding the edit to the question). You could definitely use some of what you wrote there in a proper answer. It's totally fine to be baffled by some weird behaviour, ask a question here about it, figure out what was actually going on, and then providing an answer to your own question. See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer  A nice additional test to do is to modify the `my_laptop` label in the SSH config to something else, try pinging that, and then try connecting to it with `ssh`.

Comment: As long as the name of your laptop really is`my_laptop`, this is expected behaviour. Your devices name gets registered with the local DNS. Also, there is a good chance your laptop announces its name via `mDNS`(Multicast DNS) on the local network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this behavior has nothing to do with the ssh config file. The machines on my network get DNS information from the local DNS server, running on my home router. I determined this by running `nslookup (hostname)` which shows that the machine was indeed looking at my local router to resolve the hostname in question. It just so happens that the hostname in ~/.ssh/config is the same as the one being supplied by the local DNS server.